# Hibernate - Setting null in entity collection is automatically persisted at transaction commit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dozer

Due to architecture requirements we can't use our Hibernate entities as DTOs, so we use Dozer to transform those entities to POJOs.

Our typical service looks like this:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
@Override
public Task loadTask(int taskId){
    TaskEntity taskE = taskDAO.load(taskId);
    if (taskE != null){
        taskE.setAttachments(null)
        Task task = objectMapper.convert(taskE, Task.class);
        return task;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, before transforming TaskEntity to Task we set attachments to null. This is because attachments is a lazy collection and we don't want to unnecessarily trigger the loading of those entities.

Before updating to Spring 4.1.1 this worked without any problem. However, recently we upgraded Spring from 3.2.7, leaving Hibernate at 3.6.10. Then, when executing this same code we noticed that Hibernate was executing this statement after loadTask execution:

```
update TaskAttachment set taskId = NULL where id= ?
```

That is to say, because of setting null in taskEntity.attachments, Hibernate deletes the foreign key in TaskAttachment.

**Configuration Properties**:
spring.transactionManager_class=org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereUowTransactionManager
    hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class=org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup
    hibernate.current_session_context_class=jta
    hibernate.transaction.factory_class=org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory
    jta.UserTransaction=java:comp/UserTransaction

**Session Factory Config**

```xml
<bean id="mainSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" ref="packages-mainSessionFactory" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="properties-mainSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The only ORM-related thing that we changed was that we stopped using HibernateTemplate in favour the SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().

Our former BaseDAO:

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<EntityType extends BaseEntity<IdType>, IdType extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport

    public BaseDAO(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate, Class<EntityType> clazz){
        super();
        super.setHibernateTemplate(hibernateTemplate);
        this.clazz= clazz;
    }

    public EntityType load(IdType id){
        return getHibernateTemplate().get(clazz, id);
    }
```

Our current BaseDAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public abstract class BaseDAO<EntityType extends BaseEntity<IdType>, IdType extends Serializable> implements IBaseDAO<EntityType, IdType>{

    private Class<EntityType> clazz;

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public BaseDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Class<EntityType> clazz){
        super();
        this.clazz= clazz;
        this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
    }   

    public EntityType load(IdType id){
        return (EntityType)getSession().get(clazz, id);
    }

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
```

**UPDATE:** It's not a Spring version related issue. I have checked that using **HibernateTemplate.get()** it doesn't persist the null, and with **SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get()** it does, why?

Comment: What is the issue you were facing?

Comment: Sorry I accidentallyh posted before finishing, give me 10 minutes

Comment: Which is what I would expected to happen before your upgrade already. You are changing a managed entity inside a transaction. Meaning hibernate will track all changes and when committed/ended will persist them in the database. At least that would be the case if this method is called from another `@Transactional` method. (Could you also add from which version to which version you are upgrading)?

Comment: and you **only** updated the framework or did you also change configuration, classes etc?

Comment: It certainly makes sense, what intrigues me is why it didn't persist those operations before and now it does... ???

Comment: Can you show some of the code before and after the change? Did you also introduce `@Transactional` or did you already had that?

Comment: We already had @Transactional. The service code is the same. The only change is in the DAO which instead of using HibernateTemplate calls sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() and works directly with Hibernate's API. I am not sure it has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: the only strange thing that i am not 100% sure about it , is that you changed your CRUD operations from the Template To the currentSession , which means it is loading the entities in the Global Application Cache because you are calling session.load(). So that means , every time you call the get / set method of that entity it will call a query back to DB , could you try using openSession() just to test the case?

Comment: @AntJavaDev when using Spring and declarative transactions NEVER use open session, as that will open a new session outside the scope of managed transactions and you are on your own managing the transaction and session scope.

Comment: And there is the culprit... You had `load` which doesn't really get the object (as opposed to `get`). It creates a lazy proxy, you are now obtaining a managed object.

Comment: @M. Deinum - I am gonna give it a try and let you know. Thank you for your time!! ;)

Comment: @M. Deinum - I miscopied the former DAO. We also used get in there. I have checked that using HibernateTemplate.get() it doesn't persist the null, and  with SessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get() it does (???)

Comment: @M. Deinum , yes you are right about spring's wrapping fuctionality , i am aware of that , but just to test the case , he can use openSession() and specifically manage the transaction

Comment: I suspect something wrong with your transaction setup and in the earlier case returned a detached instance and now you get an attached instance. What did you change more...

Comment: @AntJavaDev which basically defeats the purpose of having declarative tx management, you generally don't want to do manual tx management.

Comment: @M. Deinum - In the upgraded application I have now 2 DAOs, one with SessionFactory and one with HibernateTemplate. The first sets null, the latter doesn't, so It doesn't look like a setup issue. I am gonna debug HibernateTemplate to look for some hidden trick...

Comment: @M. Deinum well as you can check , he have put as  transactional the whole method , he is indicating in the transactional annotation that its read only = true and inside the method he perform two operations (select , insert/update) in a read only transaction ???? this is not defeating the purpose of having declarative tx management with a wrong config ???

Comment: Which means nothing if called from an other transactional method or when called internally.

Comment: Not a very good idea to set it null, as you are inside a transaction and hibernate tracks the transaction. Which is why it is getting persisted afterwards and it is being set to null.

Comment: I came across this question in the Help and Improvement queue. I feel that it doesn't belong there, because this is a well-asked with a clear problem statement and code provided. My only suggestion would be to move some of your relevant comments into the question body, if they helped clarify exactly where the issue was.

Comment: @James, thanks for having a look. I don't know why it was in the Help queue. I was updating the question with all the suggestions and info from the comments so I think both the question and the accepted anwer are clear enough. Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional(readOnly=true)` tells Spring that the operation will not be modifying the DB, in such a case it sets the connection to read-only and Hibernate will not update the entity. If you remove the `readOnly=true` you will see that even using `HibernateTemplate.get()` the change will be persisted.

If you use `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` you're circumventing Spring's initialization part that sets the session as readonly and therefore the changes get persisted.

Relying in `readOnly=true` to inhibit updates however is not a good practice because it is not necessarily supported by all DBs and ORMs. The best course of action is using `Session.evict()` to detach the entity. Anyway keep the `readOnly=true` because if the DB/ORM supports it then DB access could be optimized for read-only operations.

Comment: You're the man! Removing `readOnly=true` the set-null behaviour also happened with HibernateTemplate. What do you suggest doing, using Session.evict() in the BaseDAO.load() method, in the service method...

Comment: My advice is to keep the `readOnly=true` because it gives other optimizations to the transaction, but use `Session.evict()` in `loadTask()` immediately after the call to `load()` (not inside `load()` because probably you use it for other purposes). Also revert to `HibernateTemplate.get()` rather than `getCurrentSession()` unless you really need it, although with `evict()` both uses should work.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting your collection to null...change the cascade options in your entity so it doesn't save the child when saving the parent.

Comment: They are setting the collection to null to keep Dozer from drilling down into the collection entities when transferring the values to the DTO, which would trigger a lazy load. Changing the cascade type does not help with that.